# Fetch Linkedin Updates without user login

Tags: php, curl, linkedin-api

**Current Situation**

Currently I am working on a website that wants to show Linked-in updates like BBC, CNN . I have been able to fetch updates in Facebook, Twitter, Instagram using Curl function, where user authentication was not required.

In my previous project,I used simplelinkedin.class.php but there user authentication was required, for API call.

I tried CURL Linkedin API request, but returned with following error:

```
{ 
    "errorCode": 0, 
    "message": "Unknown authentication scheme", 
    "requestId": "VXUUCSY47F", 
    "status": 401, 
    "timestamp": 1435036033638 
}
```

**Questions**

- Can we fetch a profiles public updates without User authentication,
  just by using curl function like Facebook, Twitter, Instagram.
- I came to know that Linkedin had updated their api policy recently,
  but was not clear about the updates. Do we need any app permissions
  for this.

Answer (score 1):

LinkedIn does not have the  option like facebook and twitter. You will need user authentication, access token to make a request to Linked-in API. I hope this answers your first question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the [official documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition)

Its says 'Your API call will return a 403 Forbidden error if you do not have the appropriate admin permission to interact with the target company'.